# Html display attribute shows blocked

Tags: html

```
html {
    display: block;
}
```

When I inspected the element in chrome it shows this and I haven't included any style sheets as well and chrome just loads a blank page. I suppose this is the reason for it, any workarounds for this?

Comment: Yes, HTML is a block. What were you expecting?

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
 <script type="text/javascript"
 <meta charset="utf-8" />
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <title>Rocket Design - Mobile Web Design Services</title>
 </head>
<body>
  <ul>
  <li><a href="index.html" class="current">Home</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Skills</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Our Team</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</body>
</html>

Comment: All browsers have a built-in default stylesheet

Comment: Ok so any reason why it's blocking?

Comment: Please edit the question when you need to provide further info. Code in comments is unreadable.

Comment: The HTML block is a block-level element, what exactly is your problem?

Comment: Er... "block" here isn't a verb. It isn't telling you that you're blocked or anything remotely similar. It's a noun, one of the possible values of the `display` property!

Comment: It's loading a blank page because you haven't closed the <script> tag in the head.

Comment: Yes it was the script closing tag error. Didn't notice that. Very amateurish! Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1):

This is expected. The [HTML spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/rendering.html#the-page) says

```
html, body { display: block; }
```

And the [default style sheet for HTML 4](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/sample.html) contains

```
html, address,
blockquote,
body, dd, div,
dl, dt, fieldset, form,
frame, frameset,
h1, h2, h3, h4,
h5, h6, noframes,
ol, p, ul, center,
dir, hr, menu, pre   { display: block; unicode-bidi: embed }
```

And that's a good thing, it would be very strange to display the root element as inline-level.

Answer (score 0):

You have some missing closing tags in your snippet, here is what you may have:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Rocket Design - Mobile Web Design Services</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="index.html" class="current">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Skills</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Our Team</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You page is coming up blank because you haven't closed your  tag in the head.

```
<script type="text/javascript"></script>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/stk62gyk/